# Eclipse C++ Warnings

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I've recently formatted my computer and re-installed Ubuntu and Eclipse.
Afterwards, when I opened a C++ project that was both warning and error free, Eclipse now shows me some warnings I've never seen before, such as:

`Macro definition can be replaced with constexpr expression`

and

`Un- or ill-initialized variable found`

Screenshot:
[image]

What do these warnings mean and why are they listed? They weren't there before I re-installed Ubuntu and Eclipse...

Thanks!

Comment: You probably installed a new gcc version while reinstalling Ubuntu which reports additional warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Macro definition can be replaced with constexpr expression`

This means, that you've used a preprocessor macro for defining a constant. You should replace this by a C++ const expression, i.e. replace `#define PI 3.141` by `const double PI = 3.141;`.

`Un- or ill-initialized variable found`

That's pretty much self-explanatory. Always initialize your variables or you will get undefined behaviour.

The reason why the warning appear is probably that the new Ubuntu version you installed comes with a newer version of GCC which reports more warnings than the previous one. Another explanation would be that you are using other compiler options than before, for example `-Wall`.

Comment: in fact you were right about the first kind of warnings: I was using some `#defines`. but I have no idea about the other warning... here is a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/vHjoGpv.png). I am initializing them correctly...

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. This warning is generated by the built-in Eclipse static code analysis which is obviously failing in this case. Go to Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Analysis and turn the warning off there.

Comment: I just checked which warnings I have activated in my Eclipse preferences, but I don't find this specific warning anywhere. Which version of CDT are you using? It might also be that this is a custom warning someone else added to your preferences.

Comment: CDT 8.3 and here is a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ZOmk4Y8.png) of the code analysis options on my eclipse

Comment: I've never seen this specific warning before. I suspect that it's a customized code analysis rule which is provided by a plugin.